# express-rate-limit, middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, модули

Как настроить whitelist с помощью этого модуля? Гуру помогите

```
const apiLimiter = (req, res, next) => {
  const whiteList = [
    'auth0|id',
    'auth0|id',
    'auth0|id',
    'auth0|id',
    'auth0|id',
  ];

  let info;
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    info = jwtDecode(token[1]);
  }
  if (whiteList.includes(info.sub)) next();
  else {
    const limiter = new RateLimit({
      windowMs: 1000, // 1 second
      max: 50, // limit each IP to 10 requests per windowMs
      delayMs: 0, // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient, expiry: 1 }),
    });
    limiter(req, res, next);
  }
};
```

Проблема в том что такой способ создает каждый раз новый инстанс при запросе, как быть ребята?

Comment: вынеси инициализацию инстанса за пределы функции мидлвара

Comment: Как лучше потом вызывать мв,
return limiter.call(this, req, res, next)?
limiter(req, res, next);?